# makefile recursive -q mode Error 1

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run a recursive invocation of "question mode", and I get an error in a very unique scenario.

I am using MAKE 3.81, and this has been tested on two completely separate environments.

I call "make -q", then that makefile calls "$(MAKE) -C sub/a/", then that makefile calls "$(MAKE) -f ../../makefile.b"

The testcase is as simple as I can make it. Can someone tell me why I get this error:

```
nachum:/home/nachum/makefile_bug[1497]$make -q
make -C sub/a
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nachum/makefile_bug/sub/a'
make -f ../../makefile.b
make[1]: *** [b] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nachum/makefile_bug/sub/a'
make: *** [a] Error 2
nachum:/home/nachum/makefile_bug[1498]$
```

Here are the makefiles:

```
makefile:
a:
        $(MAKE) -C sub/a

sub/a/makefile:
b:
        $(MAKE) -f ../../makefile.b

makefile.b:
all:
        echo hi
```

The whole point of this exercise is to be able to check if sub projects need to be recompiled so I can properly build the top level project when necessary. Otherwise I have to use timestamps for everything. (I previously used timestamps, but I realized that caused extra confusion for other things.)

There are some weird workarounds for this problem. For example, if the recipe for a (in makefile) has an additional line above the call to $(MAKE), ie:

```
makefile:
a:
        @echo hi
        $(MAKE) -C sub/a
```

The problem goes away, AND the dependencies (in my full testcase) still work. Also using make directly seems to change the behavior (as opposed to $(MAKE)).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Nachum

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is roaming around the `-q` option specified. `-q` would run no command but give exit status if up to date. When you use `${MAKE}` `make -q -C sub/a` is executed. after little permutation and combination I found that we can't use `-q` with `-C` option. If you want quite then use `make --quite` or if you just want to check the timestamps then try with `-t` (touch but don't compile) or '-n` (dry run).

Comment: May be or there may be a reason, we need to explore yet :)